# Table of Powers

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, nested

The program should output the following using a nested for loop and preferably not use the `pow()` method if possible. Any help or advice is appreciated.Expected result:

```
1 1 1 1 1 1

2 4 8 16 32 64

3 9 27 81 243 729

4 16 64 256 1024 4096
```

My attempt at it:

```
class TableOfPowers
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        int startValue = 1;
        int y = 1;
        for (int row =0; row < 4; row++)
        {
            for (int col = startValue; col < startValue+6; col ++)
            {
                y = y *startValue;
                System.out.print(y + " " );
            }     
            System.out.println(); 
            startValue++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the problem?  Please be specific.

Comment: What result are you expecting?

Comment: Is this a task for study? It seems to be worded like a question in an assignment or test.

Answer (score 1):

Got it to work, here is my answer:

```
class TableOfPowers
{

    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        int startValue = 1;

        for (int row =0; row < 4; row++)
        { 
          int y =1;

             for (int col = startValue; col < startValue+6; col ++)
             {   

                 y = y *startValue;
                 System.out.print(y + " " );
             }

             System.out.println(); 
             startValue++;
         }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need assign `y = 1` somewhere in the outer loop.

Comment: You were spot on, thank you. Why was that necessary even though I declared it outside the loop?

Comment: @AndreasPoppmeier I edit my answer inner loop -> outer loop. Beacause of y is changed in the inner loop.